# Plone/Dexterity- How can I get the "Title" of an object's workflow state?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm trying to get the "title" of the workflow state an object is in.
I did try several things and I keep on getting the "id" of the workflow state.

One attempt that gets me the id

```
workflow = getToolByName(self.context,'portal_workflow')
status = workflow.getStatusOf("my_workflow", my_obj)
state = status["review_state"]
print state
```

Another attempt that also gave me an id

```
workflow = getToolByName(self.context,'portal_workflow')
status = workflow.getInfoFor(my_obj,'review_state')
#print type(status) returns "<type 'str'>"
print status
```

Another attempt:

```
state = api.content.get_state(obj=my_obj)
print state
```

How can I get the title of the state?  There must be something simple I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to get the `translated` workflow state of an object.
The state is usually translated within the `plone` i18n domain, so the plone UI shows your state properly. You can use `zope.i18n.translate` to get the translated state.

```
>>> workflow = getToolByName(my_obj,'portal_workflow')
>>> status = workflow.getInfoFor(my_obj,'review_state')

>>> from zope.i18n import translate
>>> translate(msgid=status, domain='plone', target_language='en')
>>> 'Published'
```

You may get the language from the language_tool.

Check http://zopei18n.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#zope.i18n.translate for more Infos.

Comment: Plus one for carefully considering multilinguality. The default-title-string should simply be gettable with `state.title`, is that correct?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, that is also giving me the id and not the title I assigned to the state in the portal_workflow.

Comment: @PatrickDowney: Were you addressing Mathias or me? Anyway, I got this of `plone.app.workflow.tests.test_plone_workflow.testStateTitles`, HTH.

Comment: @IdaEbkes: I was addressing Mathias before, but I didn't see your comment until I refreshed the page.  However, thank you for your example.  I think I was having trouble getting the actual state object (term?) and kept on getting the string representation and your example did set me on the right track.  I found something similar plone.app.contentmenu/blob/master/plone/app/contentmenu/menu.py  under def _currentStateTitle.  So I came up with this:

Comment: workflow = workflowTool.getWorkflowsFor('my.package.contenttype')[0]
print workflow.states[api.content.get_state(obj=my_obj)].title
This is ideal for my case because I only have one workflow assigned to the object.  Your example you provided however helped me though as I can build a dict and then reference a title it by passing in the state_id as opposed to using the workflow tool everytime.

Comment: @Danimal: Thanks a lot for the details of your learning-path and alternatives, it's interesting to get these insights, they are rarely explained. While I tend to pragmatism often too, it's probably worthwile to accept Mathias answer, as it's the recommandable way to go. And yeah, SO sometimes has funny effects: Just yesterday, when reading a quest, I had a comment popping up, saying it was added 1 hour ago...

Comment: @PatrickDowney: Sorry, I've mixed up your user-name with another :D